# rails update current attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a simple update action. but I have a little problem.
What I want:
If I try to change the password, I should fill an old password, but if I try t change other fields, like a name, email, old password not a required. How to write that? Help me please.

It's my old code:

```
# PATCH/PUT /users/1
def update
  if @user.authenticate(user_params[:password_old])
    @user.update_attributes(user_params)
    head :no_content
  else
    render json: { message: 'old password incorrect' }, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

Here's my changes for a new implementation:

```
def update
  if @user.authenticate(user_params[:password_old])
    @user.update_attributes!(user_params[:password, :password_confirmation])
    head :no_content
  else
    render json: { message: 'old password incorrect' }, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
  @user.update_attributes!(user_params)
  head :no_content
end
```

Comment: I deleted my answer because I might have misunderstood your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check whether a new password is set:

```
def update
  if user_params[:password] && !@user.authenticate(user_params[:password_old])
    render json: { message: 'old password incorrect' }, status: :unprocessable_entity
    return
  end
  @user.update_attributes!(user_params)
  head :no_content
end
```

Comment: Thx very much :)